# Why default values from @ConfigurationProperties class do not work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class in my Spring Boot application for [typesafe configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Properties {
    private String param1 = "val1";
    private String param2 = "val2";
}
```

Later I try to use it on fields in my beans with annotation: `@Value("${props.param1}")`

But I get the following exception on application startup until i specify a value for my custom property in `application.properties`

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'props.param1' in string value "${props.param1}"

How to make Spring Boot application to use default value without specifying value in `application.properties`?

I see the default value in IDE when i type property in `application.properties` and there is a `defaultValue` inside of generated `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file. I suppose this default value shoud be taken with spring until i oveeride it in my propertis file, but for unknown reason i get the exception from above.

Comment: How exactly did you use the `Properties` component? Using `@Value` or `@Autowired`?

Comment: @AliDehghani i mentioned, that i used @Value)

Comment: @AliDehghani i tried to set it and not set on my main class - there is no difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Later i try to use it on fields in my beans with annotation:
>   `@Value("${props.param1}")`

This so-called *Typesafe Configuration* is an alternative method of working with properties that allows strongly typed beans to govern and validate the configuration of your application.

The whole point of introducing `ConfigurationProperties` is to not use the cumbersome and error prone `@Value`s. Instead of using `@Value`, you should use the `@Autowired` to inject the `Properties` configuration:

```
@Service // or any other Spring managed bean
public class SomeService {
    /**
     * After injecting the properties, you can use properties.getParam1()
     * to get the param1 value, which is defaults to val1
     */
    @Autowired private Properties properties; 

    // Other stuff
}
```

If you're insisting to use `@Value`, first delete the `Properties` class and then use `@Value("${key:defaultValue}")` notation like the following:

```
@Value("${props.param1:val1}")
```

Comment: Looks like i had wrong imagination about typesafe properties. Thanks for explanation. Where am i supposed to use getters of configuration class? According to documentation, i can use `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: If you mean those `getParam1`, `getParam2`, etc, you can use them in any Spring managed bean (`@Repository`, `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Configuration`). Spring Boot itself used these configuration properties alot, for example, you can take a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: I see the @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation on on that link, but do not understand how it is used

Comment: Apparently, it's not required to use `@EnableConfigurationProperties`. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146207/why-default-values-from-configurationproperties-class-do-not-work/38146945?noredirect=1#comment63724652_38146494